# Diagram export from EA to document file using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, enterprise-architect

I am trying to export some diagrams from EA into a doc file. Although most of the diagrams are exported correctly few of them our getting distorted. Either their width or height is enlarged and this happens with very few of them. 
I have tried several things but not able to correct the issue.

Following is the code i am using:

EA.Project oProject = MainClass_SRS.EaRepos.GetProjectInterface();

```
oProject.PutDiagramImageToFile(diagram.DiagramGUID, SDSAddinForm.testsavediagramfilename, 1);
var img = BitmapFromUri(new Uri(SDSAddinForm.testsavediagramfilename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

var widthPx = img.PixelWidth;
var heightPx = img.PixelHeight;
var horzRezDpi = img.DpiX;
var vertRezDpi = img.DpiY;
const int emusPerInch = 914400;
const int emusPerCm = 360000;
//    var maxWidthCm = 7.00;

var widthEmus = (long)((widthPx / horzRezDpi) * emusPerInch);
var heightEmus = (long)((heightPx / vertRezDpi) * emusPerInch);

var maxWidthEmus = (long)(14 * emusPerCm);
var maxHeightEmus = (long)(18.5 * emusPerCm);


if (heightEmus > maxHeightEmus)
{
    var ratio1 = (heightEmus * 1.0m) / widthEmus;
    heightEmus = maxHeightEmus;
    widthEmus = (long)(heightEmus / ratio1);
}
```

Can someone please suggest what changes should be made so that the correct the size is exported

Comment: The above code does not touch any of EA's API. So this is eventually not EA related.

Answer (score 1):

From my diagram wrapper I use this code to extract the diagram image:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// returns diagram image
    /// </summary>
    public Image image
    {
        get 
        {
            EA.Project projectInterface = this.model.getWrappedModel().GetProjectInterface();
            string diagramGUID = projectInterface.GUIDtoXML(this.wrappedDiagram.DiagramGUID);
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
            //save diagram image to file (format ".png")
            projectInterface.PutDiagramImageToFile(diagramGUID, filename, 1);
            //load the contents of the file into a memorystream
            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
            //then create the image from the memorystream.
            //this allows us to delete the temporary file right after loading it.
            //When using Image.FromFile the file would have been locked for the lifetime of the Image
            Image diagramImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
            //delete the temorary file
            System.IO.File.Delete(filename);

            return diagramImage;
        }
    }
```

then I'm using this code to get my template object containing the image to through the serializer

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public System.Drawing.Image diagramImage { get; set; }
    // Serializes the 'Picture' Bitmap to XML.
    [XmlElementAttribute("diagramImage")]
    public string imageBase64String
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.diagramImage != null)
            {

                System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter BitmapConverter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.diagramImage.GetType());
                byte[] byteArray = (byte[])BitmapConverter.ConvertTo(this.diagramImage, typeof(byte[]));
                string imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

                return imageString;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                byte[] imageFileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                this.diagramImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageFileBytes));
            }
            else
            {
                this.diagramImage = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then in the document this is the code that inserts the image into the document

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds image
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename">image</param>
/// <param name="mainpart">main document part</param>
/// <param name="contentOpenXmlElement">element where picture will be added</param>
private static void AddImage(string filename, MainDocumentPart mainpart, OpenXmlElement contentOpenXmlElement)
{
    Picture pic = contentOpenXmlElement.Descendants().Where(x => x is Picture).FirstOrDefault() as Picture;

    if (null != pic)
    {
        byte[] imageFileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(filename);

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imageFileBytes));

        // write the image to the document
        string SigId = "b" + Guid.NewGuid();
        //var imagePart = mainpart.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/png", SigId);

        //using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(imagePart.GetStream()))
        //{
        //    writer.Write(imageFileBytes);
        //    writer.Flush();
        //}

        ImagePart imagePart = mainpart.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/png", SigId);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Position = 0;
            imagePart.FeedData(ms);
        }


        //make sure image dimensions are respected and our image is centered in the container
        if (image.Width / (double)image.Height > pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx / (double)pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy)
        {
            long oldcy = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy;
            pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy = (long)(pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx * image.Height / (double)image.Width);
            pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.Y = (oldcy - pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy) >> 1;
        }
        else
        {
            long oldcx = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx;
            pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx = (long)(pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy * image.Width / (double)image.Height);
            pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.X = (oldcx - pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx) >> 1;
        }

        pic.BlipFill = new BlipFill(new Blip { Embed = SigId }, new Stretch(new FillRectangle()));

        var element = new Drawing(new Inline(
                            new Extent { Cx = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx, Cy = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy },
                            new EffectExtent { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
                            new DocProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Picture 1" },
                            new NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                            new A.GraphicFrameLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                                    new A.Graphic(new A.GraphicData(new Picture(
                                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                                new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg" },
                                                    new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                            new BlipFill(new Blip(new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                                new A.BlipExtension { Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" }))
                                            { Embed = SigId, CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print },
                                            new Stretch(new FillRectangle())),
                                            new PIC.ShapeProperties(new A.Transform2D(
                                            new A.Offset { X = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.X, Y = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.Y },
                                            new A.Extents { Cx = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx, Cy = pic.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy }),
                                            new A.PresetGeometry(new A.AdjustValueList()) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                                            ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" }))
                                             {
                                                 DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                                 DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                                 DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                                 DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                                 EditId = "50D07946"
                                             });

        contentOpenXmlElement.RemoveAllChildren();
        contentOpenXmlElement.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to simply use

```
Repository.GetProjectInterface.PutDiagramImageToFile (string Diagram GUID, string FileName, long Type)
```

That should save the file correctly rendered in the format you specify.

There were issues with incorrectly sizing the diagrams (discussion on the forum; can't remember details). If so, try upgrading or reporting a bug.

Comment: Just found out the images which are getting distorted are taking the dimensions of images which were written to the document before them. This is not happening always but where ever it is happening the resultant image is distored. Can it be due to timing issue mainly like calculations of width and height are happening quickly and writing is slow or something. Can it be solved through threads? Please help

Comment: It might simply be that you did not save the diagram before export. The dimensions are only fixed after a save since that actually writes back everything to the database. Before its some half-baken state in memory.

Comment: I am just reading the diagrams from EA one by one and writing it to the doc file. They are not created or edited so i dont think saving could be an issue

Comment: What is your EA release?

Comment: If its the version then i am using EA 10.0 in the development environment.

Comment: Try upgrading to 12.1 to see if that fixes the issue.